# Discord.py channels, emojis, roles etc. lists into real channels, emojis, roles etc

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a `serverinfo` command and I want to put a list of all text channels, voice channels, roles and emojis. I tried with `ctx.guild.textchannels/voicechannels/roles/emojis` but it returns a list. I want to have actual discord channels, roles and emotes. I tried with maps, and it didn't work.

Comment: Hey there Mr. Praingle! Next time you ask a question here on StackOverflow, do include [code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that you have tried and errors it gave you to avoid having your question closed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is what youre looking for :

```py
@bot.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):
    text_channels = []
    voice_channels = []
    emojis = await ctx.guild.fetch_emojis()
    roles = await ctx.guild.fetch_roles()

    for individual_channel in await ctx.guild.fetch_channels():
        if isinstance(individual_channel, discord.TextChannel):
            text_channels.append(individual_channel)
        elif isinstance(individual_channel, discord.VoiceChannel):
            voice_channels.append(individual_channel)
        # FYI : There exists two other channels, category channel and stage channel
    
    await ctx.send("__Text Channels__ :\n{}".format("\n".join([f"<#{t.id}>" for t in text_channels])))
    await ctx.send("__Voice Channels__ :\n{}".format("\n".join([f"<#{v.id}>" for v in voice_channels])))
    await ctx.send("__Roles__ :\n{}".format("\n".join([f"<@&{r.id}>" for r in roles])))
    await ctx.send("Emojis :\n{}".format(", ".join([f"<{'a' if e.animated else ''}:{e.name}:{e.id}>" for e in emojis])))
```

You may work with guild info from here...
If you are going to directly use this code then be sure to embed it to have a character limit of 6000 than 2000

Also here's the result the above code will produce :
[image]

Comment: Yes, exaclty ! Thank you so much !